# How to do group permissions in a Monorepo on Github

Tags: git, github, monorepo

So we moving over to a monorepo structure and I'm left with the problem of how to restrict access to individual components within the repo on a team by team basis.
There isn't a feature on github(yet) that allows setting group permissions on subdirectories so I am wondering with all these companies already using monorepos or switching over, how do they restrict what each team can actually access?

Comment: Very easy — they don't. Really, administrative restrictions is usually enough.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more likely to get an answer on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).